# R: Density plot with colors by group?

Tags: r, colors, histogram

I have data from 2 populations.
I'd like to get the histogram and density plot of both on the same graphic.
With one color for one population and another color for the other one.

I've tried this (example):

```
library(ggplot2)
AA <- rnorm(100000, 70,20)
BB <- rnorm(100000,120,20)

valores <- c(AA,BB)
grupo <- c(rep("AA", 100000),c(rep("BB", 100000)))
todo <- data.frame(valores, grupo)


ggplot(todo, aes(x=valores, fill=grupo, color=grupo)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=3)+  geom_density(aes(color=grupo))
```

But I'm just getting a graphic with a single line and a single color.
[image]

I would like to have different colors for the the two density lines. And if possible the histograms as well.

I've done it with ggplot2 but base R would also be OK.

or I don't know what I've changed and now I get this:

```
ggplot(todo, aes(x=valores, fill=grupo, color=grupo)) + 
geom_histogram( position="identity", binwidth=3, alpha=0.5)+ 
geom_density(aes(color=grupo))
```

but the density lines were not plotted.
[image]

or even strange things like
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this ggplot2 solution:

```
ggplot(todo, aes(valores, color=grupo)) +
  geom_histogram(position="identity", binwidth=3, aes(y=..density.., fill=grupo),  alpha=0.5) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

@skan: Your attempt was close but you plotted the frequencies instead of  density values in the histogram.

Comment: What about seeing the histogram with alpha, like my second plot but also with the lines superimposed?

Comment: Thank you.  I'm always confused with where to place the aes() argument, inside ggplot or inside the other terms.   Now, how can I get thicker density lines?

Comment: And the last thing, If I want to add a plot with the stat_function(fun = dnorm.....) to add information about the normal distribution of the means....   How do you manage to get the proper y scaling?

Comment: @skan You can simply change the line width by setting `geom_density(size=1)`.

Comment: Could you eloborate what you mean by a "proper y scaling"?

Comment: OK, don't worry, I've chosen your answer because you were the first one to reply, though now the order is reversed, I don't know why.
I wanted to show on the same plot also the distribution of the sample means, but I have to scale them "artificially" in order to have more or less the same y max values and see properly the plot.

Comment: Finally I'm going to use something like this:
N <- 1000
AA <- rnorm(N, 70,20)
BB <- rnorm(N,100,20)
grupo <- c(rep("A", N),c(rep("B", N)))
valores <- c(AA,BB)
todo <- data.frame(valores, grupo)

ggplot(todo, aes(valores, color=grupo)) +
  geom_histogram(position="identity", binwidth=5, aes(y=..density.., fill=grupo),  alpha=0.5) +
  geom_density(size=1.5)+theme_bw()+ geom_vline(xintercept=c(70,100), colour=c("red", "blue"), size=1)+
and add two small segment to easily show the standard error of the means

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution could be:

```
  hist(AA, probability = T, col = rgb(1,0,0,0.5), border = rgb(1,0,0,1), 
       xlim=range(AA,BB), breaks= 50, ylim=c(0,0.025), main="AA and BB", xlab = "")
  hist(BB, probability = T, col = rgb(0,0,1,0.5), border = rgb(0,0,1,1), add=T)
  lines(density(AA))
  lines(density(BB), lty=2)
```

For alpha I used `rgb`. But there are more ways to get it in. See `alpha()` in the `scales` package for instance. I added also the breaks parameter for the plot of the AAs to increase the binwidth compared to the BB group.

[image]

Comment: What about seeing the histogram with alpha, like my second plot but also with the lines superimposed?